# I always knew JonH was a forward-thinking man, but I didn't mean it this literally

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I just happened to stumbled upon our esteemed ex-user JonH's careers profile, which I had in my browser history for some reason from a while back. (I'm blurring out his data because I'm not sure how public it is meant to be.)

The "last seen" field seems a bit off:

[image]

There's no timestamp when I hover over the "tomorrow" so I can't help debug this.

It was 21:25 WET here when I noticed it.

The system clock is OK.

All other SO/SE time stamps look normal.

When I open his Meta profile, it says "last seen: yesterday" as it probably should.

Comment: with all the code that's been posted in questions and debugged in answers you're surprised Stack Exchange have developed [the time code?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EC0mjGu24-0)

Comment: It seems like John found the flux capacitor and got his DeLorean working!

Comment: The title and the freehand drawing  to this made my day.

Comment: This makes me wonder who in their right mind thought _WET_ was an acceptable acronym for a timezone identifier

Comment: @SeinopSys guys living in the DRY zone.

Comment: No, this is correct.  You see, a single rotation of the Earth sphere, each Time corner point rotates through the other 3-corner Time points, thus creating 16 corners, 96 hours and 4-simultaneous 24-hour Days within a single rotation of Earth – equated to a Higher Order of Life Time Cube.  QED.

Comment: @Will I used to be Educated Stupid too, but then I saw the virtues of the four days and earned my Master of Cubic.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This was a bug when getting the number of relative days... we were doing the subtraction in the wrong order, so when it says tomorrow it should say yesterday ;)

It's fixed now

Comment: You should have fixed this tomorrow!

Comment: That's exactly how it went, I fixed it tomorrow ;)