# Similar questions receive orders of magnitude different number of upvotes and downvotes

Tags: discussion

The question *[Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)* received 734 upvotes, 43 downvotes, and 921 favourites.

This question (mine): *[Can a function safely return a reference to an internal static variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29292706/function-returns-reference-to-internal-static)*, which is similar, except that the variable is static, received 0 upvotes, 1 downvote, 0 favourites.

What is going on? Is it that the system shows one question more often than another?

Comment: Take a look at their age and the number of views.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - that's not the answer. Why is the number of views different? And no, I cannot "take a look at their number of views", because it is not presented.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6ohM.png

Comment: It is presented. Just to the right of the question, directly above "Featured on meta".

Comment: @user31264: it is right there in the right-hand side bar. Your question had 36 views when I just looked at it. The other question is 5 years older and has received 221 *thousand* views. That difference alone is significant when it comes to voting.

Comment: So for some reason the system presents one question to everybody, and does not present another question.  Probably it depends on *who* asked the question, and if he is from the local establishment.

Comment: Most hits to questions come from google I guess. I highly doubt it has anything to do with which questions are presented by SO or who asked the question.

Comment: @user31264 What? You're complaining because the system did not transport your question 4 years back in time so that it would get the same opportunity of being seen?

Comment: [feature-request]: Ask JonH for the recipe for [his flux capacitor](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344228/603977) and use that to restore justice to voting!

Comment: @user31264: the system does **nothing to presenting questions**. You are imagining a preferential treatment here. Google does all the presenting, based on what people search on. So in 5 years time the other question has accumulated views because it matched something people searched for more often. Your question apparently is not searched for that often.

Comment: @user31264: moreover, I note that that other question is a **community wiki post**. Who exactly is being favoured there, when the post has seen 11 different authors contribute?

Comment: @user31264: now, if you made a claim that it depends on who **answered** the question, you might have a point. The other question was answered by Eric Lippert, someone with a name for excellent, knowledgeable and helpful answers. So all you have to do is ask a question that interests Eric and perhaps can only be answered authoritatively by him, and is on topic, and is actually found by him so he knows about it. Then if he answers all you have to do is wait 5 years. Easy, right?

Comment: @user31264: "*Probably it depends on who asked the question, and if he is from the local establishment.*" Yes, us in the local establishment have special buttons to push that get our questions viewed more than others. We totally keep other questions down to promote our own. Don't mess with the Question Mafia; I hear Don Skeet takes things kinda personal.

Comment: That answer by Eric Lippert got a *lot* of attention at the time it was posted.  Memory is getting hazy but I know it was featured in the podcast and link aggregators like ycombinator.  Probably news letter and hot network question list.  Controversial too, [c++] regulars tried to close it as dup but re-opened by the Joel Spolsky.  You can't write a question up front and expect an outcome like that.  Better to spend a dollar on the Powerball lottery, odds you'll win are higher.

Comment: *Probably it depends on who asked the question, and if he is from the local establishment.* Dude, you're hilarious!  Please get a real name so I can remember you next time!

Answer (score 17):

There might be a number of reasons for this:

- Number of views: Yours has 38, the other one 221241
- Your question is less than a year old, the other one 5 years
- The other question asks about a very common programming mistake new C++ programmers make (returning the address of a function local variable), while yours asks about a more specialized scenario (returning a reference of a static function variable).
- The other answer has a really great and in-depth answer (more than 4k upvotes) explaining a lot of things to new C++ programmers.